# How to use ball style for enumerate list-

Tags: beamer, lists, enumitem

I want to use, ball style for an "enumerate list", specifically I want to include this ball item style in the part of my code where is written "ball", I have tried to add this option adding the optional command "[label=ball]", but it seems that is not working. How could I add this feature to my beamer presentation?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Conclusiones}
\begin{itemize}[label=ball]
\item En un sistema de este tipo se describen tres escenarios.\vspace{0.4cm}
\begin{enumerate}[label=$\ast$]
\setlength\itemsep{1em}
    \item \textbf{Primero:} Todas las condiciones iniciales del sistema tienden a un equilibrio a través de un estado transitorio que puede relacionarse con pequeños escenarios de crisis.
    \item \textbf{Segundo:} Se predicen de manera consecutiva periodos críticos seguidos de periodos de riqueza.
    \item \textbf{Tercero:} Todas las variables o algunas de ellas tienden a cero, lo que representa no sostenibilidad.
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Don't use the `enumitem` package with beamer, they are incompatible. Instead you can use the `ball` template that beamer provides for you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage{enumitem}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[ball]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Conclusiones}
\begin{itemize}
\item En un sistema de este tipo se describen tres escenarios.\vspace{0.4cm}
\begin{enumerate}
\setlength\itemsep{1em}
    \item \textbf{Primero:} Todas las condiciones iniciales del sistema tienden a un equilibrio a través de un estado transitorio que puede relacionarse con pequeños escenarios de crisis.
    \item \textbf{Segundo:} Se predicen de manera consecutiva periodos críticos seguidos de periodos de riqueza.
    \item \textbf{Tercero:} Todas las variables o algunas de ellas tienden a cero, lo que representa no sostenibilidad.
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You erased an important part of the code, this part consisted in the addition of an asterisk in the nested enumerate list. I need to preserve this asterisk. I am looking for the ball, just in the first enumerate.

Comment: @JuanMuñoz If you want an asterisk in the enumeration, use `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{$\ast$}`. But why are you using an `enumerate`  environment, when you won't show numbers but asterisk?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz And why are you asking for a ball in an enumerate list if you apparently want to change an itemize list? I'm confused!